# Пытаюсь написать парсер который принимает на вход аргументы

Tags: java

```
public class Pars {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Array before sort: " + Arrays.toString(args));

        public static void sort ( int[] arrayToSort){
            int indexMin;
            for (int index = 0; index < arrayToSort.length - 1; index++) {
                indexMin = index;
                for (int indexToScan = index; indexToScan < arrayToSort.length; indexToScan++) {
                    if (arrayToSort[indexMin] > arrayToSort[indexToScan]) {
                        indexMin = indexToScan;
                    }
                }
                int temp = arrayToSort[index];
                arrayToSort[index] = arrayToSort[indexMin];
                arrayToSort[indexMin] = temp;
                Arrays.toString(arrayToSort);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Мое задание звучит так:

> Программа должна принимать на вход аргументы командной строки 5 чисел
>   - в диапазоне от 1 до 10. Цель расспичатать переданные числа в первоначальном виде, а строко ниже вывести в отсортированном порядке. 
>   Вывод в консоли должен отображаться таким образом:
>
> ```
> Array before sort: [10, 5, 8, 4, 3]
> Array after sort: [3, 4, 5, 8, 10]
> ```

Вывести array before sort мне не составило труда, а вот с сортировкой трудности, и не могу понять почему так происходит, помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если воспользоваться готовым методом сортировки?

```
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class SortNumberHelp {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] ints = new int[args.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
            }
            Arrays.sort(ints);
            System.out.println("Array before sort: " + Arrays.toString(args));
            System.out.println("Array after sort: " + Arrays.toString(ints));
        }
    }
```

> Array before sort: [1, 35, 4, 5, 45, 23]
>   Array after sort: [1, 4, 5,
>   23, 35, 45]

Или задача написать свою сортировку?

Comment: Да, получилось, спасибо большое!!!!